# enable Teams app support in Outlook and Office

Tags: outlook, office-js, microsoft-teams, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

i have added a new app in to the [Dev Portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps) the manifest version on 1.13 and the apps seems to working in the Teams, But the same app is not working in Outlook
The static tab url is localhost URL, I can see the error

```
owa.ven.extframework.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Url is invalid
```

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hHaY.png)

Comment: Please have look into this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#update-the-app-manifest

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, I have followed the steps

Comment: the deployed App is logging certain log statements, but the local one throws the error

Comment: I have done a workaround to just test if the problem was with localhost URL, so in my manifest for static tabs I changed the  "contentUrl": "https://localhost:8080/" to a deployed url, it seems work, but with localhost 8080 it does not work

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, do we have any update on this ?

Comment: @umgolla - Local host URL won't work because it's scope is limited. Either you have to use ngrok tunnel URL or deployed contents URL.

Answer (score 0):

To run in Outlook and Office, your app will need to reference the npm package @microsoft/teams-js@2.0.0 (or higher). While code with downlevel versions is supported in Outlook and Office, deprecation warnings are logged, and support for downlevel versions of TeamsJS in Outlook and Office will eventually cease.

See [Extend a Teams personal tab across Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-personal-tab?tabs=manifest-teams-toolkit#update-sdk-references) for more information on that.

Comment: Hi Eugene Astafiev, - I am using Teams SDK 2.0.0

Comment: Have you checked the article mentioned in my post?

Comment: I have gone through the Document, the app which is deployed is at least logging the console.log() messages but the one which we need for localhost testing is throwing the error

Comment: @umgolla - Local host URL won't work because it's scope is limited. Either you have to use ngrok tunnel URL or deployed contents URL.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft we followed [run teams app with out ngrok](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/do-you-need-ngrok-to-develop-microsoft-teams-apps/ba-p/2353206), it work fine for teams but not outlook,. is it different for teams and outlook ?

Comment: @umgolla - You need to use the publicly available URL via running it using ngrok or using deployed app URL.